# how to add object in the null array with checking existing array

Tags: java, oop, constructor, null

I am a java beginner and I've tried to add the player in an array. I thought I successfully dealt with the problem, but it's not. I've done the following:

1. I have a split text send to create a player.
2. I have made a constructor in NimPlayer.
3. I set the array in Nimsys to save created player data.

And I have two questions:

1. It is for sure that the array will be all null at first. If I use the only array here, is that possible to add the player here?
2. I have set the `counter` for recording a created player, but I cannot do it in the else statement.

Here is my code:

```
int static counter;
public static String[] splitName(String inName) {
String[] splittedLine = inName.split(",");
String[] name = null;
if (splittedLine.length==3) {
    String userName = splittedLine[0].trim();
    String familyName = splittedLine[1].trim();
    String givenName = splittedLine[2].trim();
    name = new String[3];
    name[0] = userName;
    name[1] = familyName;
    name[2] = givenName;
}
return name; }

public static void main(String[] args) {

NimPlayer[] playerList = new NimPlayer[10]; // set an array here

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.print('$');
    String commandin = in.next();

    if (commandin.equals("addplayer")) { 
        String inName = in.nextLine();
        String[] name = splitName(inName);

        //Make sure the vadality of in name
        //Can use playerCheck to simplify the code
        if (name != null && name.length==3 && counter < 10) {
            if (playerList != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < playerList.length; i++) {
                    String userCheck = playerList[i].getUserName();
                    if (userCheck.contains(name[0])) {
                        System.out.println("The player already exist.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("The player has been created.");
                        playerList[counter++] = new NimPlayer(name[0],name[1],name[2], 0, 0);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // I have to add the player here
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input! e.g. addplayer george,Washington,George");
        }


    }
```

And my NimPlayer is:

```
public class NimPlayer {
private String userName;
private String familyName;
private String givenName;
private int score;
private int gamePlayed;



public NimPlayer(String userName, String familyName, String givenName, int gamePlayed, int score) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.familyName = familyName;
    this.givenName = givenName;
    this.gamePlayed = gamePlayed;
    this.score = score;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
public void setFamilyName(String familyName) {
    this.familyName = familyName;
}
public void setGivenName(String givenName) {
    this.givenName = givenName;
}    
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public String getfamilyName() {
    return familyName;
}
public String getGivenName() {
    return givenName;
}
public int setScore(int score) {
    return score;
}
public int getScore() {
    return score;
}
public int setGamePlayed (int gamePlayed) {
    return gamePlayed;
}
public int getGamePlayed() {
    return gamePlayed;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you may alter the array elements as you wish. So "adding" players (setting the value of an array element within array bounds) is OK.
2. The else ("// I have to add the player here") will never be reached, since `playerList` is never null.

Since all elements in playerList is initialized to null, you should check if `playerList[i]` is null before calling 
`getUserName()` (to avoid NullpointerException).

Comment: Thanks for replying. If I want to always check whether the same `username` in the `playerList`; if it's null, I could still add the player in the list. How can I do these two things?

Comment: You could define a boolean `userExists` outside the for loop, then set this to true if you find the user in the for loop.
_After_ the for loop, if userExists, put the new user in `playerList[counter++]`.
(In your current code, you are adding user if not found in playerList[0], even though it might be on another index.)

(After you make it work, you could extract the check on existing user to at method. Mind the hint "//Can use playerCheck to simplify the code".)